# Curl from thispersondoesnotexist.com fails with empty result

Tags: curl, download

I'm trying to grab generated images using curl, but when I run

```
curl https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/ > image.jpg
```

I get the error

```
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)
```

and 0 bytes are downloaded.

Adding the --http1.1 flag doesn't help:

```
 curl --http1.1 https://thispersondoesnotexist.com > imagex.jpg
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current   Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Looking at the site, I can't figure out how it actually transfers the image to the browser - I see it in the debugger, but it doesn't seem to be an output I can actually write.

I'm not trying to run a troll farm or anything, this is just a project to generate some random pictures for facial analytics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like they are rejecting curl as the user agent, so go to chrome, open network panel and reload to see the request. Here is how it looks like for me:

```
curl 'https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image' -H 'authority: thispersondoesnotexist.com' -H 'cache-control: max-age=0' -H 'dnt: 1' -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36' -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3' -H 'sec-fetch-site: none' -H 'referer: https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9'  --compressed  --output image.jpg
```